# Can I make apt-get install default to having the -y option?

Tags: apt-get, aptitude, apt

I'd like apt-get to default to using the -y option without me having to explicitly provide it.  Is this possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One option is to [alias it](http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/aliases.html).

You can add this to your `.bashrc` file:

```
alias apt-get="apt-get -y"
```

Another option is to add below config to a file at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/` 
for ex, a file called `90never-ask` at `/etc/apt/apt.conf.d/`

```
APT::Get::Assume-Yes "true";
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! You probably want to throw quotes around "apt-get -y"